# Assembly Versioning in Common Language Runtime

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, clr

Each assembly has a version number as part of its identity. As such, two assemblies that differ by version number are considered by the runtime to be completely different assemblies. This version number is physically represented as a four-part string with the following format:

major version.minor version.build number.revision

check this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51ket42z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Could someone please give a detailed definition of this, and an example possible ? I needed  real example for major version.minor version.build number.revision. I searched in net but only definition is given. i need real example for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a project in Visual studio, there is a file `Properties > AssemblyInfo.cs` (if it's not there you can just create it manually as any `.cs` file.). This file contains couple of attributes that are of interest to you

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

By changing this you give your assembly a version, which you can see if you compile it, and check it's properties. On Windows, right-click on the compiled assembly, select `Properties > Details`

A real example from Stackoverflow (see at the very bottom)

```
rev 2014.4.9.1536
```

The pattern SO uses is`%Year%.%Day%.%Months%.%Something else, maybe build number%`

Here is another example from Castle.Core, See File version and Product version

[image]

Comment: great. I learned major will be increase if any major changes happen in project and minor will be increase when enhancement (or) existing feature is changed. iam right? but what build and revision mean ?

Comment: This is subjective, so no standard rule. Build version is usually a number assigned by a build machine (see [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) for one example). Revision can refer to to a source control version (see [svn](http://subversion.tigris.org/) for example)